# How to describe screaming in a happy/excited sense?

Tags: word-choice, verbs, adjectives

I am trying to describe the action of screaming in excitement, kind of like a stereotypical fan-girl. But I'm concerned that the translations I'm finding are more along the lines of screaming in terror or pain, which is not at all the connotation I want to convey.

Some of the words I've found are:

- 泣【な】き叫ぶ【さけぶ】：to cry and shout; to scream
- 叫ぶ【さけぶ】：to shout; to cry; to scream; to shriek; to clamor
- 喚く【わめく】：to shout; to cry; to scream; to shriek; to yell; to exclaim

Although these don't seem like happy or excited emotions. The closest I have been able to find is ブヒる which is apparently manga slang for fan-girl squealing but that sounds more offensive and lesser known than what I'm aiming for. Especially since it's derived from the Japanese "oink" sound.

Can the above words be used for excited screaming or am I right in that I should be using different words?

For clarity, I am trying to describe a person as screaming in excitement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about:

> 「キャーキャー[言]{い}う」 or 「[黄色]{きいろ}い[歓声]{かんせい}をあげる」

Both are typically used to mean "to fangirl", "(for fangirls/girls) to scream/shriek" "(for fangirls/girls) to exclaim in delight / let out a cheer".

Answer (score 1):

> I am trying to describe the action of screaming in excitement, kind of like a stereotypical fan-girl.

I think you are going to have to use an adverbial phrase.
I don't think 泣き叫ぶ works, but it could be like 歓喜{かんき}のあまり叫{さけ}び声{ごえ}をあげる.

If it's a little kid I think it's キャッキャッと はしゃぐ／はしゃぎ回{まわ}る*／大{おお}はしゃぎする. It has a pleasant tone, quite a typical expression though. (*回る for running around the place.)

歓喜{かんき}に喚{わめ}く sounds like more loud and noisy. Typically it's わーわー(と)わめく.

Answer (score 0):

**わいわい**騒{さわ}ぐ is used for excited cheering/screaming
- also, **がやがや**